# Eliminate extra isPresent() call from Optional produced by Java Stream

Tags: java, option-type

I'm a relatively novice Stream user and I feel like there should be a cleaner way to accomplish what I have below. Is it possible to accomplish what the code below does all within a single Stream (eliminating the if/else at the bottom)?

Thanks!

```
Optional<SomeMapping> mapping = allMappings.stream()
     .filter(m -> category.toUpperCase().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(m.getCategory().toUpperCase().trim()))
     .findAny();         
if (mapping.isPresent()) {
     return mapping.get();
} else {
     throw new SomeException("No mapping found for category \"" + category + "\.");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `orElseThrow` to throw an exception if the `Optional` is empty:

```
return
    allMappings.stream()
               .filter(m -> category.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(m.getCategory().trim()))
               .findAny()
               .orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException("No mapping found for category \"" + category + "\"."));
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! I was close, but couldn't quite get the syntax correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `toUpperCase()` as you are comparing with `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

```
return allMappings.stream().filter(m -> category.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(m.getCategory().trim()))
                       .findAny()
                       .orElseThorw (() -> new SomeException("No mapping found for category \"" + category + "\."));
```

Comment: Now that there is [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60191230/4) on the other answer and otherwise as well the suggestion that you're making should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Derp, thanks for pointing that out!